# Найти вхождение ключа в строке

Tags: python

Подскажите, как найти вхождение ключа в строке? Естъ словарь:

```
dictionary = {"My name": "", ...[далее более 1000 ключей]}
```

Есть строка:

```
mystring = "Hello, my friends! My name is Bob"
```

Можно это решить с помощью регулярки, если да, то как?

Comment: может это ? http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 1):

[[@Xyanight](/users/5234/xyanight)](/users/5234/xyanight) найти все ключи, содержащиеся в mystring

```
 [x for x in dictionary.keys() if mystring.find(x) > -1]
```